# How to mix component level scss and global styles in nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sass, font-awesome, next.js

I am using *Font Awesome* in my project and want to change the styling of a component when the user clicks on it. Here is the *React* code:

```
    <div
      role="button"
      onClick={() => toggleMenu(menu => (menu = !menu))}
      className={`${styles.toggleButton} ${close ? styles.showMenu : ""}`}
    >
      <i className="fal fa-horizontal-rule" />
      <i className="fal fa-horizontal-rule" />
      <i className="fal fa-horizontal-rule" />
    </div>
```

And here is the scss code:

```
.toggleButton {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  cursor: pointer;

  i.fal {
    line-height: 8px;
    transition: transform 300ms ease-in-out;
  }
}
```

My problem is that the `i.fal` style does not get applied, as *nextjs* renders it like this `Header_toggleButton__2nd_H`. One solution I can think of would be add a custom class to the `<i/>` tags, but how can this be done without nextjs prepending the global `fal` classes? Furthermore, this approach strikes me as cumbersome, isn't there a more elegant not so verbose solution?

Thanks for any help.

**EDIT:**
I use the [Component-Level SCSS](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/built-in-css-support#adding-component-level-css) style.

> CSS Modules locally scope CSS by automatically creating a unique class name

Answer (score 1):

I happen to this yesterday. My solution is absolutely to use `SCSS` code style

```js
    <div
      role="button"
      onClick={() => toggleMenu(menu => (menu = !menu))}
      className={`toggleButton ${close ? showMenu : ""}`}
    >
      <i className="fal fa-horizontal-rule" />
      <i className="fal fa-horizontal-rule" />
      <i className="fal fa-horizontal-rule" />
    </div>
```

the style which next native supports is useful in CSS, but in SCSS, I need the nested selectors, so I abandon the native usage. you can try this.

Comment: Well, it does not work using *Component Level scss*. Which is unfortunate, because I like that solution.